# Querying the Apple AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-search-api

I'd like to be able to gather information about the apps that a particular user has deployed/registered under their Apple ID.  I know that Apple has an iTunes search API available, but I don't see any way to query given an Apple ID (typically represented as an e-mail address).  Is there any way to do so?  Are there any other search APIs that I've missed that provide this functionality?  I know that I can query for an app using the "artistId" parameter, but can't find a way to map the numeric value for the artistId to an Apple ID.  Thoughts?

Comment: This information is not something Apple makes available through any of their official information sources, including enterprise partner feeds. So Dimtry's answer might be your best bet (i.e. use the artist name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't expect Apple to give access to private information. The best you can do (if that helps you at all) is search app store for artist, say Tapbots

```
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=tapbots&entity=allArtist
```

And then use that ID to search all their apps.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iTunes API is the only search mechanism provides, you'll have to use a combination of filters from http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching